# Add more files on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, file

I've seen websites where there is a box for the user to browse a file to upload, then an "Add more files" link. When the user clicks on the link, another box shows up, allowing the user to chose another file. And the user can click "Add more files" to keep adding boxes. How do they do this?

I'm using Ruby on Rails as my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="filePickers">
  <input type="file" name="files[]">
  <input type="file" name="files[]">
  <input type="file" name="files[]">
</div>
```

That will appear as an array of files on `params[:files]` when posted to your server.

If you want more, bind some Javascript to a button somewhere to add new inputs.

```
// jQuery for brevity
$('#filePickers').append('<input type="file" name="files[]">');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTML5 "drag & drop upload", based on two HTML5 APIs:

- [HTML5 Drag and Drop API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dnd)
- [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI)

You can find a tutorial to implement it manually [here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/)

But you would rather use a library that implements it already, like for example [jquery-filedrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop)